# Insert value from select box into database

Tags: php, html, database

I have a post text website on http://www.youngcreatitivy.se

You see on http://www.youngcreativity.se/post.php that I have a post method. And on the bottom of the page I have like a option to choose which category your text is in. I've founded this code for inserting value from select box into my database. Here it is:

```
<?php


//insert category to database
if(isset($_POST['qty'])) {
// Fetch and clean the <select> value.
// The (int) makes sure the value is really a integer.
$qty = (int)$_POST['qty'];

// Create the INSERT query.
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`quantity`)
        VALUES ({$qty})";

// Connect to a database and execute the query.
$dbLink = mysql_connect('server', 'username', 'password') or     die(mysql_error());
          mysql_select_db('database_name', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

$result = mysql_query($sql);

// Check the results and print the appropriate message.
if($result) {
    echo "Record successfully inserted!";
}
else {
    echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
}
}
?>
```

Thats the Php code.

Here's the html code:

```
     Qty: <select name="category">
        <option value="1">Quote</option>
        <option value="1">Poem</option>
        <option value="1">Novel</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
    </select>
```

I understand the code, but how should I create the database in phpMyAdmin? And how can I get so that If I click submit after choosing the category and typed in my text it post the text and it writes which category I chosen in the database?
Please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your first language is not English - 'Qty' is a common abbreviation for 'Quantity', so the code you are re-using is more about numbers.

You need to change the original `<select>` to something like -

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="Quote">Quote</option>
    <option value="Poem">Poem</option>
    <option value="Novel">Novel</option>
</select>
```

As your code is, the select will only ever return 1.

Also, you need to escape the value returned before you store it in the database. `mysql_real_escape_string` is your friend in this case - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php - otherwise you are open to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in localhost. Then you have to go to

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

There you find the way to create database and tables you can get easily. But you r in server if you have cokntrol panel there you see phpmyadmin with logo. There you click on that your phpmyadmin will be opened.Same as localhost. Hope this helps to you.
Ramsai

Comment: Yeah, I know phpmyadmin. I'm not on localhost. But how many rows should I create in the table? And should I name them after the options: Quote, Poem and Novel?

Comment: by seeing your code above my idea is to create a table with field names id and quantity thats all. As you are inserting the quantity value only na thats why

Comment: Should quantity be a varchar or int?

Comment: id->int(50) and primary key and not null, quantity-> varchar(50)/int(50). Whatever you give no problem

Comment: And I should name the table "table"?

Comment: Ok, now I have created the database. So what should the code for choosing a option in the drop down box be?

Comment: But now, when I press submit and chosen a option it just refresh the site and add nothing to the database...

Comment: Did you put form tag? <form name="xyz" method="post" action="">here your code comes</form>

Comment: Yup, I did.  <form name="xyz" method="post" action="">
  <select name="category">
    <option value="Quote">Quote</option>
    <option value="Poem">Poem</option>
    <option value="Novel">Novel</option>
  </select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
</select>
</form>